# jQuery - how to get data name?

Tags: jquery, css, selector

I have many div with "data-value" attribute. But only one with class name ".selected". I need to make selector with both. Data + class name.

How to make selector with data atribute and class name ?

HTML

```
<div data-value="x">Click Me!</div>
<div data-value="y">Click Me!</div>
<div class='selected' data-value="z">Click Me!</div>
<div data-value="w">Click Me!</div>
```

jQuery

```
alert( $("div[data-value] .selected").data('value') );  // this is wrong way...
```

Comment: `$("div[data-value].selected").data('value')` Remove space, [Descendant Selector (“ancestor descendant”)](https://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/) selector

Comment: Thank you, your solution works fine. :-)

Answer (score 6):

There are two ways to get `data` attribute:

```
$(".selected").attr('data-value');  // It works for all type of custom attribute
```

or

```
$(".selected").data('value');  // This one is specially for data attribute
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with jQuery's attr():

```
alert($('div').attr('data-value'));
```

But, since there will me more than one divs, better give each one a class (to be more specific):

```
<div class="clickable" data-value="x">Click Me!</div>
<div class="clickable" id="second" data-value="y">Click Me!</div>
<div class='selected clickable' data-value="z">Click Me!</div>
<div class="clickable" data-value="w">Click Me!</div>
```

and the jQuery will be:

```
$('div.clickable').on('click', function(){

    alert($(this).attr('data-value'));

});
```

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/hpb5u62e/

Answer (score 1):

check working example.I have added click event for button

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
      alert( $(".selected").attr('data-value') );
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-value="x">Click Me!</div>
<div data-value="y">Click Me!</div>
<div class='selected' data-value="z">Click Me!</div>
<div data-value="w">Click Me!</div>
<button>Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

you initial locator `$("div[data-value].selected")` is correct, except you don't need space before `.selected`, as with space - you'll search not elements `div[data-value]` , but elements inside `div[data-value]` with that class `selected` (and you have nothing inside data-value)

Comment: While this looks a valid answer (and simpler than the up-voted answers from April 2010, at that), I have to look close to see what it adds to [Satpal's near-instantaneous comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43320306/jquery-how-to-get-data-name#comment73704769_43320306) (describe effect of this extraneous whitespace).

Answer (score 1):

[`Mayank Pandeyz`'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43320475/3367974) is correct, but there is some difference between [`data`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) and [`attr`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) in jQuery:

When you set data using `attr`, e.g: `$(element).attr('data-name', 'john')`

- You can read the value of `data-name` using

  - `$(element).attr('data-name')`
  - `$(element).data(name)`
  - `element.getAttribute('data-name')`
  - `element.dataset['name']`
  - `element.dataset.name`
- It is publicly visible on the element upon inspection
- Value can not be object

When you set data using `data`, e.g: `$(element).data('name', 'john')`

- You can read the value of `data-name` only using `$(element).data(name)`
- Value can be object
- It's not publicly visible on the element upon inspection

And the reason of that is this 2 store the value in 2 different places. `attr` stores data directly on the element in attributes, and for `data` data are stored internally in jQuery.

*p.s: do not set data using `data` and read it using `attr` and vice versa. use either `data` or `attr`*